# How do I make Excel cell contents show a different value

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an Excel VSTO file that makes a chart with the help of the data entered.
Whenever a cell gets a value 'e' it sums the value of all other cells and displays the result in that cell.

I want the cell to keep showing the value 'e' instead of the sum that is calculated.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just give the cell a NumberFormat of `"e"`. This will display `e` but not change the underlying value of the cell...

You will need to escape the quotation marks.

```
Target.NumberFormat = "\"e\"";
```

---

NB.

(this method will only work if the underlying value of the cell is a number).

Comment: I am using the same approach but the excel sheet is displaying
        1900
instead of 
        e

Comment: Are you including the `"`s?

Comment: I am doing

    Target.NumberFormat = "e";

Comment: Still getting 1900 instead of    e

Comment: @ZunairZubair You will need to escape the quotation marks if you're setting it in code.. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Select the cells you want to format and run:

```
Sub ChangeToText()
    Dim DQ As String, mesage As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    mesage = DQ & "e" & DQ
    Selection.NumberFormat = mesage & ";" & mesage & ";" & mesage & ";"
End Sub
```

You will need to adapt this to **c#**